# Test class not covered need to increase coverage

Tags: unit-test, scheduled-apex

I wrote scheduler class and test class which is covered 70%.
but some part not covered
[image]

Scheduler class:

```
global class PartnerLeadtoAccountScheduler implements Schedulable {

    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {

        map < Id, Account > mapAccount = new map < Id, Account > ();

        set < string > checkDuplicateEmail = new set < string > ();
        set < Id > updateSet = new set < Id > ();
        set < Id > conflictSet = new set < Id > ();
        set < String > emailEntry = new set < String > ();

        List < Partner_Lead__c > partnerLead = [Select id, Business_Nature__c, Company_Name__c, Contact_Number__c, Contact_Person__c, Date__c, Designation__c, Email_Address__c, Package_Plan__c, OwnerId, CP_Name_Text__c, createddate FROM Partner_Lead__c WHERE Email_Address__c != Null];
        system.debug('--partnerLead--' + partnerLead);

        List < Partner_Lead__c > partnerLead1 = [Select id, Business_Nature__c, Company_Name__c, Contact_Number__c, Contact_Person__c, Date__c, Designation__c, Email_Address__c, Package_Plan__c, OwnerId, CP_Name_Text__c, createddate FROM Partner_Lead__c WHERE Email_Address__c != Null order by createddate asc];
        Map < string, schema.RecordTypeInfo > rtName = schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName();
        Id rt = rtName.get('Lead').getRecordTypeId();

        Map < string, schema.RecordTypeInfo > rtName1 = schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName();
        Id rt1 = rtName.get('Merchant').getRecordTypeId();

        mapAccount = new Map < Id, Account > ([SELECT id, Subscription_Email__c, Channel_Partner__c, Closure_Source__c, RecordTypeId FROM Account]);
        for (account acc: mapAccount.values()) {
            checkDuplicateEmail.add(acc.Subscription_Email__c);
        }

        system.debug('mapAccount' + mapAccount);

        Map < String, Partner_Lead__c[] > assotiactedServiceByEmail = new Map < String, Partner_Lead__c[] > ();

        List < Partner_Lead__c > partnerleadToBeUpdated = new List < Partner_Lead__c > ();
        List < Account > accountList = new List < Account > ();
        List < Account > updatedAccountList = new List < Account > ();

        Map < string, Account > mapSAB = new Map < string, Account > ();
        Map < string, Account > mapUpdatedSAB = new Map < string, Account > ();
        Partner_Lead__c plead;
        for (Partner_Lead__c pl: partnerLead) {
            plead = new Partner_Lead__c(id = pl.id);
            if (!checkDuplicateEmail.contains(pl.Email_Address__c)) {

                Account acc = new Account();
                acc.LastName = pl.Contact_Person__c;
                acc.RecordTypeId = rt;
                acc.Business_Type__c = pl.Business_Nature__c;
                acc.Company_Name__c = pl.Company_Name__c;
                acc.Phone = pl.Contact_Number__c;
                acc.Designation__c = pl.Designation__c;
                acc.Subscription_Email__c = pl.Email_Address__c;
                acc.AccountSource = 'Channel Partner';
                acc.Channel_Partner__c = True;
                acc.Package_Plan__c = pl.Package_Plan__c;
                acc.CP_Name__c = pl.OwnerId;
                acc.Cp_Date__c = DateTime.valueOf(pl.createddate).Date();
                acc.CP_Name_Text__c = pl.Company_Name__c;
                // system.debug('--acc--'+acc.Id);
                //plead.Updated__c=true;
                accountList.add(acc);  

                // partnerleadToBeUpdated.add(plead); 

            }
            if (checkDuplicateEmail.contains(pl.Email_Address__c)) {

                Map < string, schema.RecordTypeInfo > rtName2 = schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName();
                Id rt2 = rtName.get('Lead').getRecordTypeId();

                Map < string, schema.RecordTypeInfo > rtName3 = schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName();
                Id rt3 = rtName.get('Merchant').getRecordTypeId();


                Account ac = [Select Id, Subscription_Email__c, RecordTypeId from Account where Subscription_Email__c = : pl.Email_Address__c Limit 1];
                system.debug('--ac--' + ac);
                system.debug('--rt3--' + rt3);
                system.debug('--rt2--' + rt2);
                updatedAccountList.add(ac);
                if (mapAccount.get(ac.Id).Closure_Source__c == 'Organic' && mapAccount.get(ac.Id).RecordTypeId == rt3) {
                    mapAccount.get(ac.Id).Channel_Partner__c = true;
                    mapAccount.get(ac.Id).Closure_Source__c = 'Channel Partner';
                    mapAccount.get(ac.Id).CP_Name__c = pl.OwnerId;
                    mapAccount.get(ac.Id).CP_Name_Text__c = pl.Company_Name__c;
                    mapAccount.get(ac.Id).Cp_Date__c = pl.Date__c;
                    mapAccount.get(ac.Id).Package_Plan__c = pl.Package_Plan__c;
                    //plead.Updated__c=true;
                    //system.debug('--plead.Updated__c--'+plead.Updated__c);
                    //mapAccount.get(ac.Id).Updated__c = true;
                    //inserFlag = false;
                    //updateFlag = true;
                    //partnerleadToBeUpdated.add(plead); 
                } else if (mapAccount.get(ac.Id).Closure_Source__c != 'Organic' && mapAccount.get(ac.Id).RecordTypeId == rt2) {
                    mapAccount.get(ac.Id).Channel_Partner__c = true;
                    mapAccount.get(ac.Id).CP_Name__c = pl.OwnerId;
                    mapAccount.get(ac.Id).CP_Name_Text__c = pl.Company_Name__c;
                    mapAccount.get(ac.Id).Package_Plan__c = pl.Package_Plan__c;
                    mapAccount.get(ac.Id).Cp_Date__c = pl.Date__c;
                    //plead.Updated__c=true;
                    //system.debug('--plead.Updated__c--'+plead.Updated__c);
                    //mapAccount.get(ac.Id).Updated__c = true;
                    //inserFlag = false;
                    //updateFlag = true;  
                    //partnerleadToBeUpdated.add(plead); 
                }
            }
        }
        List<Partner_Lead__c> pllist=new list<Partner_Lead__c>();
        if(accountList!=null){
        for (Account acc1: accountList) {
            system.debug('--acc1--' + acc1);
            mapSAB.put(acc1.Subscription_Email__c, acc1);
            system.debug('--mapSAB--' + mapSAB);
        }
        }
        for (Account acc1: updatedAccountList) {
            system.debug('--acc1--' + acc1);
            mapUpdatedSAB.put(acc1.Subscription_Email__c, acc1);
            system.debug('--mapUpdatedSAB--' + mapUpdatedSAB);
        }

        if (!mapSAB.values().isEmpty()) {
            insert mapSAB.values();
            system.debug('--mapSAB.values()--' + mapSAB.values());

        }


        update mapAccount.values();

        //Populating Account lookup on partner lead object
        for(Partner_Lead__c pl :partnerLead){
            system.debug('--mapSAB acc id--'+mapSAB.get(pl.Email_Address__c));
            //system.debug('--mapAccount acc id--'+mapAccount.get(pl.Email_Address__c));
            if(mapSAB.get(pl.Email_Address__c)!=null){
                pl.Account__c=mapSAB.get(pl.Email_Address__c).id;               
                system.debug('--pl--'+pl);
            }
            else if(mapUpdatedSAB.get(pl.Email_Address__c)!=null){
                pl.Account__c=mapUpdatedSAB.get(pl.Email_Address__c).id;                
                system.debug('--pl--'+pl);
            }


         pllist.add(pl);   
         system.debug('--pllist!!!!--'+pllist);  
        }



        //List < Partner_Lead__c > pllist = new list < Partner_Lead__c > ();
        Integer cnt = 0;
        for (Partner_Lead__c pl: partnerLead1) {
            cnt++;
            plead = new Partner_Lead__c(id = pl.id);
            system.debug('--IF-Condition----' + checkDuplicateEmail.contains(pl.Email_Address__c) + ' && ' + !emailEntry.contains(pl.Email_Address__c));
            system.debug('--emailEntry-----' + emailEntry);
            if (!(emailEntry.contains(pl.Email_Address__c))) {
                plead.Updated__c = true;
                //updateSet.add(pl.Id);
                emailEntry.add(pl.Email_Address__c);
                system.debug('--IF-cnt-' + pl.Email_Address__c);
                /*
                if (mapSAB.get(pl.Email_Address__c) != null) {
                    plead.Account__c = mapSAB.get(pl.Email_Address__c).id;
                    system.debug('--plead--' + plead);
                }
                */
            } else {
                system.debug('--else-cnt-' + pl.Email_Address__c);
                plead.Conflict__c = true;
                // conflictSet.add(pl.Id);
            }
            partnerleadToBeUpdated.add(plead);
        }
        system.debug('--accountList--' + accountList);

        update partnerleadToBeUpdated;
        update pllist;
        system.debug('--pllist--' + pllist);
    }

}
```

Test class:

```
@isTest
public class TestPartnerleadtoAccountscheduler {

        static testmethod void test1() 
        {
            Test.startTest();
             Partner_Lead__c P = new Partner_Lead__c();
                P.Business_Nature__c='IT';  
                P.Company_Name__c='PWC';
                P.Contact_Number__c='7894561230';
                P.Contact_Person__c='jacob';
                P.Date__c=System.today();
                P.Designation__c='Tester';
                P.Email_Address__c='grace1456@gmail.com';
                P.Package_Plan__c='1';
                P.CP_Name_Text__c='Anurag Avula';
                P.Updated__c=true;
                insert P;

                Profile pro = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='System Administrator'];

                User u=new User();
                u.Alias = 'standt';
                u.Email='newuser3@testorg.com'; 
                u.EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8';
                u.LastName='Testing';
                u.LanguageLocaleKey='en_US'; 
                u.LocaleSidKey='en_US';
                u.ProfileId = pro.Id; 
                u.TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles';
                u.UserName='newuser344@testorg.com';
                insert u;

                Account A = new Account();
                A.LastName=P.Contact_Person__c;
                A.Subscription_Email__c='grace1456@gmail.com';
                A.Channel_Partner__c=true;
                A.Closure_Source__c='Organic';
                a.Business_Type__c='Product';
                a.Company_Name__c='Test';
                a.Phone='23456789';
                a.Designation__c='Salesforce Developer';
                a.AccountSource='Channel Partner';
                a.Package_Plan__c='CapTree';
                a.CP_Name__c=u.id;
                a.Cp_Date__c=date.today();
                a.CP_Name_Text__c='Test';
                insert A;
            PartnerleadtoAccountscheduler scheUpdateAccount = new PartnerleadtoAccountscheduler();
            String sch ='0 57 * * * ?';    //This will run at 57th minute of any given hour. 
            System.schedule('Schedule to update Account Name', sch,scheUpdateAccount);  
            Test.stopTest();
        }

    static testmethod void TestPartnerleadtoAccountscheduler()
    {   
        Test.starttest();


        Partner_Lead__c P = new Partner_Lead__c();

        P.Business_Nature__c='IT';  
        P.Company_Name__c='PWC';
        P.Contact_Number__c='7894561230';
        P.Contact_Person__c='jacob';
        P.Date__c=System.today();
        P.Designation__c='Tester';
        P.Email_Address__c='grace123@gmail.com';
        P.Package_Plan__c='1';
        P.CP_Name_Text__c='Anurag Avula';
        P.Updated__c=true;
        insert P;

        Profile pro = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='System Administrator'];

        User u=new User();
        u.Alias = 'standt';
        u.Email='newuser1@testorg.com'; 
        u.EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8';
        u.LastName='Testing';
        u.LanguageLocaleKey='en_US'; 
        u.LocaleSidKey='en_US';
        u.ProfileId = pro.Id; 
        u.TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles';
        u.UserName='newuser1456@testorg.com';
        insert u;


        Account A = new Account();
        A.LastName=P.Contact_Person__c;
        A.Subscription_Email__c=null;
        A.Channel_Partner__c=true;
        A.Closure_Source__c='Organic';
        a.Business_Type__c='Product';
        a.Company_Name__c='Test';
        a.Phone='23456789';
        a.Designation__c='Salesforce Developer';
        a.AccountSource='Channel Partner';
        a.Package_Plan__c=P.Package_Plan__c;
        a.CP_Name__c=u.id;
        a.Cp_Date__c=system.today();
        a.CP_Name_Text__c=P.Company_Name__c;
        insert A;

        Test.stoptest();
    }

    static testmethod void TestPartnerleadtoAccountscheduler1()
    {   
        Test.starttest();


        Partner_Lead__c P1 = new Partner_Lead__c();
        P1.Business_Nature__c='IT';  
        P1.Company_Name__c='PWC';
        P1.Contact_Number__c='7894561230';
        P1.Contact_Person__c='jacob';
        P1.Date__c=System.today();
        P1.Designation__c='Tester';
        P1.Email_Address__c='grace123456@gmail.com';
        P1.Package_Plan__c='1';
        P1.CP_Name_Text__c='Anurag Avula';
        P1.Updated__c=true;
        insert P1;

        Profile pro1 = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='System Administrator'];

        User u1=new User();
        u1.Alias = 'standt';
        u1.Email='newuser1@testorg.com'; 
        u1.EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8';
        u1.LastName='Testing';
        u1.LanguageLocaleKey='en_US'; 
        u1.LocaleSidKey='en_US';
        u1.ProfileId = pro1.Id; 
        u1.TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles';
        u1.UserName='newuser14564@testorg.com';
        insert u1;

        Account A1 = new Account();
        A1.LastName=P1.Contact_Person__c;
        A1.Subscription_Email__c='grace123456@gmail.com';
        A1.Channel_Partner__c=true;
        A1.Closure_Source__c='Organic';
        a1.Business_Type__c='Product';
        a1.Company_Name__c='Test';
        a1.Phone='23456789';
        a1.Designation__c='Salesforce Developer';
        a1.AccountSource='Channel Partner';
        a1.Package_Plan__c='CapTree';
        a1.CP_Name__c=u1.id;
        a1.Cp_Date__c=date.today();
        a1.CP_Name_Text__c='Test';
        insert A1;

        Test.stoptest();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`A.Subscription_Email__c='grace1456@gmail.com';` Just changed this email address in your test class account record. It will solve your problem.

Because you are comparing this with Partner email address and both must be different to match your condition.